# Is there a tool that allows logging of memory usage?

Tags: memory, monitoring

I want to monitor memory usage of a process, and I want this data to be logged. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Also [Get maximum memory usage of linux executable](http://serverfault.com/questions/179604/get-maximum-memory-usage-of-linux-executable), [monitor a program's memory usage in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563168/monitor-a-programs-memory-usage-in-linux)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have written [a script to do exactly this](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/Syrupy).
It basically samples `ps` at specific intervals, to build up a profile of a particular process. The process can be launched by the monitoring tool itself, or it can be an independent process (specified by pid or command pattern).

Answer (score 30):

Occasionally when the need arises I just do:

```
$ top -d 1 -b |grep <process> >>somefile
```

It's not an elegant solution, but gets the job done if you want the quick crude value to verify your hypothesis.

Comment: I think it _is_ elegant in it's simplicity.  You may want to do `grep --line-buffered <process> >>somefile` to force grep to output each line without buffering

Comment: An explanation of the top arguments: `-b` sets top to batch mode, suitable for outputting to other processes, and `-d` sets a delay in seconds for each update. Altogether this command outputs lines from top every 1 second and appends to `somefile`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to append anything to `somefile` for me. I am using `top -d 1 -b | grep 2597  >>somefile`, `somefile` gets created, but is always empty. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 8):

`sar` ([System Activity Reporter](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar)) from the [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) package is your friend in case like these.

Another way would be monitoring combined with historical data, e.g. Munin, pnp4nagios, rrdtools, ...

Comment: but can `sar` be focussed on just one process? mostly it seems to monitor the system as a whole

Comment: The `pidstat` command also from the sysstat package provides a fairly nice interface for reporting statistics on single process.

Comment: @xenoterracide Steven D had the answer. I wasn't aware of this command before.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the aforementioned sar, I'd recommend [atop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atop). It saves a binary log that you can peruse afterwards, and besides memory saves a lot of other information.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

> Valgrind is an instrumentation
>   framework for building dynamic
>   analysis tools. There are Valgrind
>   tools that can automatically detect
>   many memory management and threading
>   bugs, and profile your programs in
>   detail. You can also use Valgrind to
>   build new tools.
>
> The Valgrind distribution currently
>   includes six production-quality tools:
>   a **memory error detector**, two thread
>   error detectors, a cache and
>   branch-prediction profiler, a
>   call-graph generating cache and
>   branch-prediction profiler, and a **heap
>   profiler**.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This document [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to monitor memory usage of a process, and I want this data to be logged. Does such a tool exist?

Yes, can achieve exactly this, a bit more with [Procpath](https://pypi.org/project/Procpath/) (author here).

In the simplest case you point it to the PID of interest and let it record its Procfs metrics including Resident Set Size (RSS). By default it makes a recording per 10 seconds (for the target process, its ancestors and descendants).

```
$ procpath record -d tgt.sqlite -p $PID
```

When you think it has recorded enough datapoints, `Ctrl+C` it and this will give you the recordings.

```
$ sqlite3 tgt.sqlite "SELECT ts, stat_rss * 4 rss_kib FROM record WHERE stat_pid = $PID"
1635349330.11141|478460
1635349340.12125|476068
1635349350.13124|480232
1635349360.14117|483416
...
```

Using a SQLite GUI can be a more convenient to explore and query the database (e.g. `apt install sqlitebrowser`).

Procpath can also visualise RSS of the target process into an SVG out of the box like this:

```
$ procpath plot -d tgt.sqlite -f tgt.svg -q rss -p $PID
```

[image: resident set size plot]

If you're running Kernel 4.14+ you can get more advanced Linux memory usage metrics like Proportional Set Size (PSS), Unique Set Size (USS), proportional swap usage and others (see the documentation for what you can get from [`/proc/{pid}/smaps_rollup`](https://procpath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/procfs.html#procpath.procfile.SmapsRollup)):

```
procpath record -d tgt.sqlite -p $PID -f stat,cmdline,smaps_rollup
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Sridhar's simple answer but I rolled my own before I tried his:

```python
#! /usr/bin/python3

import json, psutil, datetime, sys, time

while True:
  print(json.dumps((datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
                    psutil.Process(int(sys.argv[1])).memory_info()._asdict())))
  time.sleep(1)
```

It's basically only useful if you want structured output. Note: `_asdict()` was broken in some versions of Python 3.5; it works again in Python 3.6.9 though (as well as in Python 2.7.17).

Output looks like:

```js
["2019-03-19T11:21:53.784670", {"rss": 220389376, "vms": 538984448, "shared": 15724544, "text": 303104, "lib": 0, "data": 221364224, "dirty": 0}]
["2019-03-19T11:21:54.786136", {"rss": 220438528, "vms": 539119616, "shared": 15724544, "text": 303104, "lib": 0, "data": 221499392, "dirty": 0}]
["2019-03-19T11:21:55.787555", {"rss": 220495872, "vms": 539119616, "shared": 15724544, "text": 303104, "lib": 0, "data": 221499392, "dirty": 0}]
["2019-03-19T11:21:56.788754", {"rss": 220528640, "vms": 539119616, "shared": 15724544, "text": 303104, "lib": 0, "data": 221499392, "dirty": 0}]
```

For me, it was important to have structured output so that I could more easily consume it for analysis.

Comment: "use Python 2" yeah, don't.