# Is there a tool that can monitor bandwidth usage of a single process?

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

I've found [a nice monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/is-there-a-tool-that-allows-logging-of-memory-usage/5790#5790) which allows me to log a variety of runtime data of a single process. I'm looking for an equivalent that does the same for bandwidth usage. Ideally, the command should look like `bwmon --pid 1 --log init.log`. Is there such? Can it run without admin privileges?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/189128/something-that-logs-network-traffic-bandwidth-usage-per-process

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/36586/how-can-i-monitor-network-i-o-usage-per-process-under-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something to get you started (just in case you want to write it yourself):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# usage: bwmon PID

IN=0; OUT=0; TIME=0

get_traffic() {
    t=`awk '/eth0:/ { printf("%s,%d,%d\n",strftime("%s"),$2,$10); }' < /proc/$1/net/dev`
    IN=${t#*,}; IN=${IN%,*}
    OUT=${t##*,};
    TIME=${t%%,*};
}

get_traffic $1
while true
do
    _IN=$IN; _OUT=$OUT; _TIME=$TIME
    get_traffic $1
    echo "$TIME,$(( $TIME - $_TIME )),$IN,$(( $IN - $_IN )),$OUT,$(( $OUT - $_OUT))"
    sleep 1
done
```

comments:

- checks only eth0
- checks every 1 second
- works only under linux, but other unixes work similar (procfs or whatever)
- output could be stored into a sqlite.db with `stat --printf="%N\n" /proc/PID/exe | cut -d ' ' -f 3`

Comment: I don't think this is actually a per-process counter; I think it's just the total interface count from the process' point of view.  I ran a client/server `nc` pair over localhost, sending one byte per second, and watched `/proc/<listening-nc-pid>/net/dev`.  Then I ran a second `nc` pair, sending at maximum rate.  The file I was watching very obviously counted the second pair's data along with the first pair's.  Running on Linux 2.6.32.

Comment: I had an error `function strftime never defined`; it was fixed by installing **gawk**.

Comment: @Jander That's correct, `/proc/<pid>/net/dev` and `/proc/net/dev` have the same content here. Hence the scipt only reports the traffic for eth0, not for the given process.

Comment: Confirming that this is not an answer. It measures the interface counter for `eth0`, as seen by the process. It does *not* count data sent by the process through that interface.

Comment: @Navin an answer is anything that tries to answer the question. A *wrong* answer is still an answer. If this one is wrong, then you may downvote it, but it's still an answer.

Comment: Accepted answers should at least be correct.

Answer (score 7):

If you're satisfied with general I/O bandwidth used (or if your program does almost entirely network I/O), then you could watch the `/proc/<pid>/io` file.  You want the `rchar` and `wchar` fields.  You might want to subtract `read_bytes` and `write_bytes`, since they represent reads and writes to the storage layer.  See section 3.3 of http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt.

If you need more resolution.... you could maybe script this using `lsof` and `strace`, though it would be painful to get all the corner cases right.  The basic idea is to parse the output of `strace -p <pid>`, grabbing the first parameter (= the file descriptor) and the return value (= number of bytes) from `read()`, `write()`, `send()`, and `recv()` calls (**NOTE** there are several more syscalls to listen for; I haven't tracked them all down).  Discard negative values; they indicate errors.  Use `lsof -p <pid>` to figure out which file descriptors are TCP/UDP sockets, and add up the counts per fd.  This strategy doesn't require root as long as you own the process you're inspecting, but it would be really hairy to write, let alone write well.

Answer (score 4):

try [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/):

> NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic down per protocol or per subnet, like most tools do, it groups bandwidth by process. NetHogs does not rely on a special kernel module to be loaded. If there's suddenly a lot of network traffic, you can fire up NetHogs and immediately see which PID is causing this. This makes it easy to indentify programs that have gone wild and are suddenly taking up your bandwidth.

Comment: Sadly, it can't monitor a single process, and it doesn't log. The second requirement (logging) is much more important that the first one though. Oh, and it doesn't run without admin privileges :(

Comment: You'll almost certainly need root privileges for this.

Comment: You could try using nethogs with the -t flag (tracemode). The resulting output could then be parsed to extract the traffic of the single process you're interested in.