# How can I test the system footprint of applications?

Tags: memory, performance, monitoring

I am about to develop a piece of software and I want to ascertain the impact it has on my system. The main things I am look for are load times, memory and CPU usage and shutdown time, although I would like to get as much information as possible. I know I can use my distro's system monitor to get some of this stuff, but I need precise data as I am going to be doing some before and after tests during my project. Is there anything out there (preferably open source) that will suffice?

Comment: For memory usage, see [Is there a tool that allows logging of memory usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/is-there-a-tool-that-allows-logging-of-memory-usage) and the many other questions it cites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking that you need software profilers eg:
for memory I use [valgrind massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) with linuxtools on eclipse.

If you are not restricted by system/gpl try dtrace on solaris/sunos if not try systemtap(eclipse + linuxtools) or gprof if you have source code.